# Vue.js: conflict v-html and a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, vue-component, directive

Here is the template of the component for a notification:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <li class="g-line-height-1_2">
   <router-link :to="linkFromNotification(item)"
               @click.native="readNotification(item)"
               v-html="item.message"
               :class="activeNotification">
  <br>
  <span class="g-font-size-12 g-color-gray-dark-v5">
    {{ getTime }}
  </span>
   </router-link>
  </li>
  <li>
   <hr class="g-my-0">
  </li>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import moment from 'moment';


export default {
 props: ['item'],
 computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    'getLastNotifications',
    'getNotifications',
  ]),
  activeNotification() {
    if (this.item.viewed === true) {
      return 'nav-link g-bg-gray-light-v5--hover g-px-20 g-py-10 u-link-v5'
    } else {
      return 'nav-link g-bg-primary-opacity-x--hover g-bg-primary-opacity-x2 g-px-20 g-py-10 u-link-v5'
    }
  },
  getTime() {
    moment.locale('ru');
    return moment(this.item.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z').fromNow();
  },
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions([
    'notifications',
    'readNotification'
  ]),
  linkFromNotification(item) {
    if (item.notification_type === 'user_subscribed') {
      return {name: 'person', params: {id: item.object_id}}
    } else if (['comment_created', 'answer_selected', 'answer_created'].includes(item.notification_type)) {
      // TODO: link must be constructed with hash
      return `/posts/${item.object_id}#${item.anchor}`;
    } else if (item.notification_type === 'user_coauthored') {
      return {name: 'show_post', params: {id: item.object_id}}
    }
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Every notification gets a text from a server using `v-html`. Now I can see the text of the notification but I cannot see the time of it. It seems like my function `getTime` is overlapped by something in the `router-link`. When I try to put `<span>` with the function `getTime` under the `router-link`, the notification time is displayed but my page layout is getting collapsed. Please help!

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) `v-html` replaces all children with the html.

Comment: So there is no way to get rid of this behaviour?

Comment: Put the `v-html` on a span where you want it.

Comment: Omg! It works now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RoyJ you should make your solution as an answer, not  a comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-html` sets the content of the element it is attached to. Any content inside the containing tags will be overwritten. To add HTML to existing content, make a `<span>` where you want the HTML inserted and put your `v-html` on that span.

Comment: I did this and now it works. Thank you! It's good to remember such nuances in Vue.js.